# QPointer check is NULL?

Tags: qt, qpointer

When I delete the object the `QPointer` is pointing to, I check the value of the `QPointer`, and it is not `NULL`, but when I check its `isNull` function, it returns `true`.

And more strangely, when I do (`!m_qpointer`) it also returns `true`.
So how is this possible?

Comment: "When I delete the object the QPointer is pointing to ", yes, you are deleting the object, rather than the pointer.

Comment: --->Object , now delete Object: ---->MemoryAddressOfObject, As you can see the pointer is still there and pointing to the same address, but the object is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(!m_qpointer)` returns true when you delete the object it is pointing to, because of this operator defined in `qpointer.h`:

```
inline operator T*() const
    { return static_cast<T*>(const_cast<QObject*>(o)); }
```

It returns the pointer it is guarding. If it has been deleted, then it will be null.

`isNull()` returns true if the pointer it is guarding is null:

```
inline bool isNull() const
    { return !o; }
```

Now I'm not sure what do you mean by *I check the value of the QPointer, and it is not NULL*. Why should it be null? The `QPointer` object should still be a valid object even after deleting the pointer it is guarding.